# Доставка php-кода на бэкэнды

Tags: php, apache, nginx, gitlab, непрерывная-интеграция

Категорически приветствую! Допустим, у меня есть локальный gitlab и веб схема, где в роли фронта nginx который просто проксирует все запросы на apache бэкэнды, где, собственно apache2.4 и php7.2, - всё очень просто. Так вот мне нужен способ (желательно на примере) как доставить php код из гитлаба на все бэкэнды? Я нашёл вот такой [способ](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/laravel_with_gitlab_and_envoy/index.html) в офф документации, но во-первых я ни разу в глаза не видел laravel/envoy, во-вторых хотелось бы знать как в 2к19 это принято делать. В общем, буду рад любым вариантам.